# Jenkins Groovy pass variables to parallel runs

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am having problems figuring out how to pass some variables into the parallel runs in the Jenkins groovy script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call(version, project) {

    sh '''#!/bin/bash
    [[ ! -e ${WORKSPACE}/target/rpm/${project}/RPMS/ ]] && mkdir -p ${WORKSPACE}/target/rpm/${project}/RPMS/
    (( $(ls ${WORKSPACE}/target/rpm/${project}/RPMS/*.rpm | wc -l) != 0 )) && rm ${WORKSPACE}/target/rpm/${project}/RPMS/*.rpm
    cd ${WORKSPACE}/scripts/fpm_requirements && bundle install && bundle show fpm
    '''

    parallel (
        "package foo": {
            sh '''#!/bin/bash
            export PATH=$PATH:~/bin:~/.gem/ruby/gems
            cd ${WORKSPACE}/scripts/fpm_requirements
            echo Project is ${project}
            echo Version is ${version}
            echo Iteration is $(echo ${version} | cut -d . -f 3)
            '''
        },
        "package bar": {
            sh '''#!/bin/bash
            export PATH=$PATH:~/bin:~/.gem/ruby/gems
            cd ${WORKSPACE}/scripts/fpm_requirements
            echo Project is ${project}
            echo Version is ${version}
            echo Iteration is $(echo ${version} | cut -d . -f 3)
            '''
        }
    )
}
```

So the version and project variables are populated in the first shell that is called but when they hit the two parallel runs they are not being pulled in.

I have tried a few different options to pass them in but none have worked.

Does anyone have any relevant ideas that might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the `'''` to `"""`. In Groovy, string inside single/triple quote won't trigger string interpolation, but string inside single/triple double quote will do that.

So the `${version}` and `${project}` in your Shell script will be treated as variable from Shell context, but actually they are exist in Groovy context.

More about Groovy String at [here](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings), Below option 2 more suitable for your issue.

**Option 1)** using `""` or `"""`

```
   "package foo": {
        sh """#!/bin/bash
        export PATH=\$PATH:~/bin:~/.gem/ruby/gems
        cd \${WORKSPACE}/scripts/fpm_requirements
        echo Project is ${project}
        echo Version is ${version}
        echo Iteration is \$(echo ${version} | cut -d . -f 3)
        """
    },
    "package bar": {
        sh """#!/bin/bash
        export PATH=\$PATH:~/bin:~/.gem/ruby/gems
        cd \${WORKSPACE}/scripts/fpm_requirements
        echo Project is ${project}
        echo Version is ${version}
        echo Iteration is \$(echo ${version} | cut -d . -f 3)
        """
    }
```

Attention: need to escape the `$` ahead of `${WORKSPACE}` and `$(echo ..)`, because we hope `$` be kept after interpolation.

**Option 2)** using `'` or `'''` and inject `version` and `project` into Environment Variables of Shell context.

```
def call(version, project) {
    env.version=version
    env.project=project
    // Groovy env api used to inject groovy value into environment variable
    // so that you can refer groovy value later in shell script

    // still use ''' in following code, no need to change
    ...
```

Comment: So I tried that and while it works for Project/Version Iterations fails: "command substitution: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token" suggesting that the version var is empty.

Comment: I forgot to use `"""` in the second shell script, I updated it. Please try again.

Comment: I noticed the shell script you used complex and long, so I post the option 2 to resolve your issue, which is more easy, just add two more line codes to inject groovy value: `version` and `project` into Environment variable by `env.xxx` api

Comment: Adding env.version and env.project is the answer. The script then goes on to run "fpm" which throws some different errors but this answers the question perfectly!